# Joining distinct counts from another table per group

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, distinct

I have 2 tables:

`table_1`

```
date    id_1         name           id_2        transaction_id
202116  1            Google         235         ABAF51
202116  1            Google         489         GHH512
202116  1            Google         973         JDDF12
202116  1            Google         1189        HDFTS1
202116  1            Amazon         207         HSDY12
202116  1            Amazon         3329        KFGJD88
202116  1            Amazon         3360        JHTJDS1
202116  1            Facebook       862         SYTAHJ4
```

`table_2`

```
date    id_1        name            id_2
202116  1           Google          22
202116  1           Google          102
202116  1           Google          104
202116  1           Google          196
202116  1           Amazon          228
202116  1           Facebook        230
202116  1           Google          235
202116  1           Google          240
```

I am trying to have a table like so:

```
date    id_1        name            id_2        transactions
202116  1           Google          22          1
202116  1           Google          102         3
202116  1           Google          104         4
202116  1           Google          196         2
202116  1           Amazon          228         3
202116  1           Facebook        230         7
202116  1           Google          235         3
202116  1           Google          240         2
```

Where `transactions` is the `DISTINCT COUNT` of `transaction_id` from `table_1` per group of `date, id, name, id_2` ( mapped to `table_2` and joined by `date, id, name, id_2` )

So, the idea would be to count distinct `transaction_id` from `table_1` values for

```
date    id_1         name           id_2       
202116  1            Google         235
```

And assign the value ( let's say 1 ) to `table_2` column `transactions` where:

```
date    id_1         name           id_2       transactions
202116  1            Google         235        1
```

And so on for each combination of `date, id_1, name, id_2`.

What I've tried:

```
select jp.date, jp.id_1, jp.name, jp.id_2, count(distinct(transaction_id)) from table_2 jp
left join table_1  using(date, id_1, name, id_2)
group by jp.date,jp.id_1, jp.name, jp.id_2,transaction_id
```

But it does not give me the correct output.
How can I achieve the desired result

Answer (score -1):

without knowing the details of your table structure it's a bit hard, but why don't you solve the problem in 2 steps:

1. count distinct `transaction_id` from `table_1` for `date, id, name, id_2` with

```
with first_selection as (
select date, id, name, id_2, count(distinct transaction_id) nr_transactions
)
```

2. join the result with `table_2`

```
select t.date,
 t.id,t.name, 
 t.id_2,
 fs.nr_transactions 
from table_2 t 
join first_selection fs 
 on t.date=fs.date
 and t.id = fs.id
 and t.id_2 = fs.id_2
 and t.name = ft.name
```

with the complete query being

```
with first_selection as (
select date, id, name, id_2, count(distinct transaction_id) nr_transactions
)

select t.date,
 t.id,t.name, 
 t.id_2,
 fs.nr_transactions 
from table_2 t 
join first_selection fs 
 on t.date=fs.date
 and t.id = fs.id
 and t.id_2 = fs.id_2
 and t.name = ft.name
```